# svn changes my files names

Tags: svn, unix, command-line, sudo

I'm using command line SVN 1.6.5 on my Ubuntu 9.10. This is my first time using it on the latest Ubuntu, I found svn confused about file names. The problem was as follow:

I firstly used

`sudo svn co http://my-repository/h2m h2m`

after successfully checkout these files, I immediately used

`svn st` and found

```
dean@notebook:~/FAT32/h2m$ svn st
?       license                  
?       readme                   
?       cnt/readme               
!       cnt/README               
?       doc/changes              
!       doc/CHANGES              
?       data/readme              
!       data/README              
?       octave/readme            
!       octave/README            
!       LICENSE                  
!       README
```

Looks like

I find checked my `\h2m\data\` folder and find there is a file called `README`.

I also checked my server repository:

```
dean@notebook:~/FAT32/h2m/data$ svn list http://my-repository/h2m/data
README
digits.m
digits.mat
digits.sig
```

### **This is strange,I'm looking forward to hearing from your.**

BTW: I'm using dualboot, I found the files are working perfectly on my Windows 7 which was using Tortoise SVN.

Thanks again.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on in here.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that looks wrong is that you've checked out as root (sudo) and then used normal user account.

Another thing is filesystem case sensitivity. I would expect weirdness like that when working with fat32 partition. Maybe checking mount options will help.

Comment: Yep, that's probably what's wrong. Remove the existing checkout, and re-check out without the "sudo" command. Don't ever use root without a specific purpose. ESPECIALLY don't ever copy-paste a command from the internet that starts with sudo.

Comment: @Paul — While I agree you shouldn't be mixing users in the same working copy (and probably shouldn't be using root at all), I doubt that's the cause of the problem.  I think @hacker has the right of it — if this is a drive shared between the two OSes, it's probably FAT32, which doesn't preserve case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most probably related to the fact that the filesystem is case insensitive. You should check what the options for mounting the filesystem are, and in particular disable automatic conversion to lower case. Subversion treats the file names as case sensitive, but your current file system is converting it to lower case, and thus the result of the status:

> ?       cnt/readme
>   !       cnt/README

That means that subversion believes it created a file named `cnt/README` but that file is not present in the current file system (`!` mark means *deleted*), and at the same time if sees `cnt/readme` as a new file present in the filesystem but that was never added to subversion)

Fix your mount options, or use a case sensitive filesystem, and you will be fine.